PostgreSQL: CheckConstraint based on another Column
In PostgreSQL, I want a check constraint if column "Art" (this never is NULL) is == 'Typ 3' and three other columns either all NULL or all NOT NULL.
My code fails for the first record having 'Type 2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL.
ALTER TABLE "SandBox"."T Test" 
ADD CONSTRAINT  "T Test_Serie_check" CHECK (
    "Art" = 'Type 3' 
    AND (
         ("ID-Serie_fkey" IS NULL     
          AND "Type" IS NULL     
          AND "Nr" IS NULL     
          AND "NrTotal" IS NULL)
        OR
         ("ID-Serie_fkey" IS NOT NULL 
          AND "Type" IS NOT NULL 
          AND "Nr" IS NOT NULL 
          AND "NrTotal" IS NOT NULL)
        )
    );

How to solve this?

Your constraint only allows entering the value 'Type 3' for Art. If you want to be able to insert 'Type 2', then that is not the constraint you want. What do you actually want?

Thanks, I wand t a constraint to check only records having Art = 'Type 3'; if so, the other three columns need to be either all NULL or all NOT NULL. If Art = 'Type 1' or Art = 'Type 2' there should be no check.

Then you need an IF (an implication), not an AND

Would you please provide more code? I don't understand ...

Like this?
ALTER TABLE "SandBox"."T Test" ADD CONSTRAINT  "T Test_Serie_check" CHECK ( IF "Art" = 'Type 3' THEN ( ("ID-Serie_fkey" IS NULL     AND "Type" IS NULL     AND "Nr" IS NULL     AND "NrTotal" IS NULL) OR ("ID-Serie_fkey" IS NOT NULL AND "Type" IS NOT NULL AND "Nr" IS NOT NULL AND "NrTotal" IS NOT NULL) ) );
NO: SyntaxError at »IF«

Yes, although the syntax for that is CASE WHEN … THEN … END, and you need an ELSE TRUE. Or you simplify to "Art" <> 'Type 3'  OR (… all null …) OR (… all not null …).

Thanks, solved it with `CASE WHEN … THEN … ELSE ... END'

In cases like this Postgres provides a quite useful pair of functions: num_nulls() and num_nonnulls(). Given a list of columns they return the number of columns that are either null or not null as appropriate. This may make you code easier to read by elminating case structure. (see demo here)
constraint serie_check check (    art <> 'Type 3' 
                              or  art = 'Type 3' and 
                                  num_nulls (fkey, type, nrtotal) in (0,3) 
                             )

